# LiveCD ver 20.4.1 for AMD64 does not run

Tags: boot, 20.04, live-cd

Live CD loads and runs on a multi-core AMD-64 box. The same CD over on my single-core AMD64 is giving me no joy. I end up with a splintered screen with horizontal lines, no menus and I have to bomb out of attempted LiveCD run by holding power button for 4 seconds.

I have tried flashing Phoenix BIOS so that it included Power Management. I have wiped my hard drive to a blank. I have Knoppix 8.5 LiveCD running with no problem. DO I suspect my graphics card?

Comment: Yeah, try adding 'nomodeset' at boot time. Press F6 and select it from the live CD at boot.

Comment: That did work. The desktop looks like 'safe mode'. That is I have desktop with a huge cursor arrow. Display looks like it is old VGA mode instead of 1920x1040.

Comment: I tested three GPU cards.-- VGA, DVI and HDMI. VGA absolutely would not give a desktop or lock screen because of shattered graphics. DVI cable works on another monitor but the monitor I will be using only has VGA and HDMI connections. So, I bought and installed the GPU card I really didn't want to gain Ubuntu 20.4.1. I would guess Knoppix Linux ran on my original hardware because they do support VGA. Mint, which is based on Ubuntu, gave the same shattered screen graphics with the horizontal lines.New GPU card displays all current flavors of Linux.